# Fisher & Paykel Aerocare Dryer — Drum turns when door closed, Code 151

Tags: appliances

On a Fisher & Paykel Aerocare dryer #DE7027J1US0: our dryer gets into an error state where Code "151" is displayed on the control panel, and the **drum motor turns immediately** when the door is closed.

The drum stops spinning when the door is open, but the drum turns ON again ***as soon as*** the door is closed (even when the dryer is not "on".)

Local appliance company has quoted $300 for a new circuit-board and $200 for a service call.  Is there a fix that costs less than $500?

Comment: Some googling says 300 for the board, but easy to buy and is plugged in, just pull old one and push in new one.

Comment: Agreed, but my dryer **already had** the board replaced once a few years ago, and now it's failed again for the **same reason.**   Quite a few people have posted about the same problem on different forums, so it seems to be a design problem.

Comment: For the price of the board, since it seems to be on going, might think about replacing the dryer.  Should be cheaper than a couple of boards.

Comment: I can confirm that opening up the top of the dryer and accessing the control board to tap the orange relay worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same problem appears to affect both DE7027J1 and DE7027G1 models. In my case, my dryer already had the main circuit-board replaced ($200) and the same problem happened after a few years, on the new circuit-board.

According to online [postings](https://www.fixya.com/support/t27077695-fisher_paykel_aerocare_dryer_keeps#cmnt_3670231), the problem is caused by a stuck relay on the main circuit board -- a $3 part.  You may not even need to replace the $3 part.  You also don't need to replace the $200-300 circuit board.

A relay is a mechanical switch.

## Temporary Fix

1. Pull the dryer away from the wall.  **Unplug the dryer**.
2. Open the control panel using two screws at the rear.[image]
3. Set the control panel upside down on top of the dryer.  **There should be a yellow slip of paper taped to the inside of the panel.**  This has some service information for the repair technician, including troubleshooting tips, the error code and an electrical wiring diagram.

> According to this piece of paper, Code 151 is DRUM FAILURE.  We already knew that.

4. Look at the control board, surrounded by white plastic box and attached to the dryer with two screws. **Take a photo of the wire harnesses with your camera phone.**
5. Carefully remove all the wiring harnesses from the control board. Most of the wiring plugs use rocker-style "latches" and need to be pinched in order to remove.
6. Remove the two screws holding down the control board & cover.  Set aside (these should be shorter than the first  screws, keep them separate).
7. Open the cover to reveal the motherboard.  You don't need to fully remove the motherboard from the bottom half of the white-plastic box.

[image]
(Motherboard shown fully removed from the plastic box, but this is not necessary for your repair).

8. Notice the ORANGE relay.   This relay is stuck in the ON position.

> Expert mode:  You can verify this by testing the 5-pin connector above the relay with your
> multimeter and notice that pins #3-4, LINE and DRUM, have connectivity.   They **shouldn't** have connectivity, until the dryer is turned on by the computer.

Flick the ORANGE relay five to ten times with your finger.  Rap on it with your index finger, or knuckle, five to ten times.  This may reset the relay.

> Expert mode:  The LINE and DRUM pins should now be "open" when tested with your multimeter.

9. Reassemble by reversing the steps above.  Use the photo of the wiring to help put the wires back into the correct plugs more quickly.
10. When you plug in the dryer, the drum should now NOT turn on, and the dryer should start up normally.
11. This fix should be good for a few months, until the relay becomes stuck again.  Then you can repeat the steps.
12. Be cheerful that this saved you a $200-500 service call.  When you can longer stand doing the temporary fix every few months, you can look into the ''permanent fix'' below.

## Possible Permanent Fix

**This part of the solution is not verified and expert feedback is welcome.**

The orange relay has the following markings.

TE Electronics, Austria, #RZ03-1A4-D012-R

This part is available from many electronic supply houses for approximately $3.00 (USD, 2021).  According to user @Bill at Fixya.com, you can replace the relay.

However, this relay appears to be soldered to the printed-circuit board, so replacing it may be an expert-only fix. Additionally, it's not clear that replacing this component with an identical component will be a long-term solution.

## Possible Next-Level Permanent Fix

According to the same @Bill at Fixya.com forums,

> to take it to the next level- if you don’t want to do this again in 6 to 12 months: across the 2 contact points on the board, you will need to add a snubber. This will stop the contacts from arcing and burning up. Mouser item # 504M02QA220 - 220ohm ½ watt resistor in series with a 0.5 uf metal polyester film cap [capacitor]. Solder this between the power line pin and line to drum motor.

I have not verified this solution and would welcome feedback from the community.

Comment: The temporary fix method worked fine in the case of mu dryer. Thanks.

Comment: Cool!  Glad this worked for you.

Comment: This is brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

Hit the top of the dryer with a rubber sole shoe, a good smack will free the relay and the dryer will work normally until the next time.

Comment: This sounds like just a simple version of step 8 in [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/238275/34147).

Comment: If the shoe method works, without opening the top of the dryer, that's great!